# Setting a vim variable to a python output

Tags: python, vim

How would I do something like the following in vim:

```
echom "hello"
pyx print('New item')
let a = (pyx import socket; socket.gethostname())
echom a
```

The first and second lines work; but how to assign a variable name to a python value/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import module `vim` and execute vim's command `let` passing value from Python:

```
:py3 import socket, vim; hn=socket.gethostname(); vim.command('let vim_hn="'+hn+ '"')
```

`hn=…` assigns a variable in Python; `'let vim_hn="'+hn+ '"'` passes its value to command `let`; something like `let vim_hn="myhost"`; [`vim.command()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#python-command) executes that `let` from Python.

Now you can inspect the value in vim:

```
:echo vim_hn
```

Comment: `no module named vim` -- does this require an additional library to play nice with vim in python?

Comment: actually not bad at all. I simplified it to: `py3 import socket; vim.command("let vim_hn='%s'" % socket.gethostname())
echom "The hostname is: " . vim_hn`

Comment: @David542 Never saw this. Any chance you run the command in an external Python? Module `vim` is only available in built-in Python, of course.

Comment: yea, exactly. And it's auto-imported, so that import statement isn't even required. Actually I was surprised how simple it was to use python here.

Answer (score 1):

I've [experimented a few approaches](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-clang/blob/V2Upgrade/autoload/clang.vim)

- I prefer `:let vimvar = pyxeval('PythonExpression')` from vim code when possible
- Sometimes `vim.command('let vimvar = ...')` makes more sense, in particular from Python code.